# EntLib 5 Wrap Handler Message Localization

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resources, localization, enterprise-library

I have been asked, at very short notice of course, to implement exception logging to the Windows Application event Log in one of our products (vb.Net, framework 3.5, WinForms) using EntLib 5. In and of itself this is fine - I can get that working. However, this is for a client who wants messages in Chinese. Certain parts of the app have language resource files and I found a couple of sentences in my MS EntLib Developers Guide book which suggested that I could use an external resource to provide a localised 'friendly' message in a wrap handler within the Exception Handling Block.

Unfortunately there was no mention of how to actually achieve this but it seemed straightforward enough. I added a new resource to a resx file which lives at the project level for the project which is common to all areas of the application and re-built to project so that the satellite assemblies were built. I then specified the name of the resource in the 'Message Resource Name' field within the EntLib configuration console. the problem arises when I try and specify the 'Message Resource Type'.

I clicked on the search button and found the satellite assembly I needed, but it did not get added to the list of loaded assemblies and therefore I couldn't select it. The problem is that none of the places where I've seen this feature mentioned actually demonstrate how to get it working so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The search for the assembly will only let me select a dll or exe so I assume I am supposed to reference the satellite assembly somehow but how do I do this if it won't add it to the list of loaded assemblies?

One point to note is that we have a main executable which then calls numerous class libraries to load areas of functionality as required, and the config file we use throughout is the one which belongs to the main executable. Is it the case that you can only use satellite assemblies which are related to the assembly that the config file belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet fully utilized this feature yet but just something to check, are you using the fully qualified name of the assembly?

EDIT: A potentially applicable link - http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/67460

Comment: Hi there. Yes I was using the fully qualified name of the assembly but unfortunately it turns out some legacy components of ours use EL v3.1 and we don't have the time to upgrade them without risk (I now have one day to get this working and shipped - over-promising consultants be damned!) so I've had to downgrade to 3.1 for the time being which means I no longer have the ability to use an external resource. However I will be returning to this at some point in the near future and since the link you provided seems like it might be quite helpful I've awarded you the answer.Cheers